# What does P ∈ (0, 1] mean?

Tags: notation

I am reading an article. I find this expression P ∈ (0, 1].

Would be possible in math to have interval shrouded by  parentheses and square bracket. If yes, what does it mean?

As far as I know the interval can be like this P ∈ (0, 1).

Comment: Usually, it means that $P$ belongs to the set of all numbers between $0$ and $1$, including $1$, but not $0$.

Comment: Simply $0<P\le 1$.

Comment: [Notations for intervals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Notations_for_intervals)

Answer (score 4):

It means $0<P\leq 1$.  In general, if $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, then $[a,b]$ means $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:a\leq x\leq b\}$ and $(a,b)$ means $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:a<x<b\}$.  The notation $(a,b]$ is a sort of hybrid, and means $\{x\in\mathbb{R}:a<x\leq b\}$.

Comment: Thank you @Eric Wofsey

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark ✓ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).